# Identify a cylinder or thick washer for bolts

Tags: identification, components

It must be obvious to you but I can't figure out the name of that part which I need to replace. It's added to the bolts that hold the PCB to the case so as to create a large enough gap between the two. It's basically a metal cylinder.

[image]

Comment: To me it seems a board spacer.

Comment: Also called a standoff. Keystone Electronics: http://www.keyelco.com/ is my go-to outfit for stuff like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've heard them called standoffs and spacers. [McMaster-Carr](http://www.mcmaster.com/#spacers/=j92rny) seems to make the distinction between if they're threaded (standoffs) or not (spacers).

Comment: This is an important, IMO, distinction to make. You use spacers to slide over bolts and separate two or more boards, whereas you'd use a standoff to thread into a hole and create a raised plane with which to secure a board.

Comment: @Shamtam, Some standoffs (the way McMaster defines them) have female threads at both ends.

Answer (score 3):

These are known as spacers, or stand-offs.

Don't bother using McMaster-Carr for these if you're outside the USA. Firstly their web site won't let you look at more than two pages. Secondly they won't do business with you because of the 'complexity of shipping internationally'.

You're much better off using someone like [Farnell](http://www.farnell.com). They are happy to ship to *loads* of countries around the world.

[image: Farnell Shipping countries]

[A spacer at Farnell.](http://export.farnell.com/nsf-controls/mas3-spacer-220012-3mm/spacer-ma-3mm/dp/1165271)

Comment: good point about international shipping. You can also find spacers and standoffs at most local hardware stores, though the selection and availability may be questionable.